# Are the predictions from Random Forest Regression bounded by the max and min in the data set?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

Since the expected value that minimises the error at each leaf is used for prediction does this mean that the forecasted values can never be smaller than the smallest value in the dataset or bigger than the largest?

Comment: In short, yes, your assertion is correct. See [Random forest regression not predicting higher than training data](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235189/random-forest-regression-not-predicting-higher-than-training-data)

Comment: Thanks @Firebug, good to know I was on the right track but unfortunately it makes RF unsuitable for my problem.