# Why random forest loses stability on new data, but GMDH works great

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I made a toy dataset where the test part doesn't look like a train. I would like to know why `random forest` works so bad compared to GMDH (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_method_of_data_handling)).

**my question**
why does `random forest` lose stability on test data and `GMDH` no?
[image]

```
set.seed(111)
s <- function(ve=1:500,a,f,p)    a*sin(f*ve+p)
s1 <- s(a = 1, f = 0.01, p = 0)    + rnorm(500,sd = 0.05)
s2 <- s(a = 0.5, f = 0.06, p = 2)  + rnorm(500,sd = 0.05)
s3 <- s(a = 0.1, f = 0.12, p = 4)  + rnorm(500,sd = 0.05)

X <- cbind(s1,s2,s3)
Y <- s1 +  s2  +  s3 


tr <- 1:300
ts <- 301:500


library(randomForest)
rf <- randomForest(Y[tr]~.,X[tr,],ntree=500,mtry=ncol(X))
rf_pred <- predict(rf,X)

library(GMDHreg)
gmdh <- gmdh.gia(X = X[tr,], y = Y[tr], prune = 5, criteria = "PRESS")
gmdh_pred <- predict(gmdh, X)[,1]

par(mfrow=c(2,1),mar=c(2,2,2,2))
matplot(X,t="l",lty=1) 
abline(v=length(tr),col=1,lty=2,lwd=2)

plot(Y,t="l",col="gray90",lwd=10,main="Target")   
abline(v=length(tr),col=1,lty=2,lwd=2)
lines(rf_pred,col=2,lwd=1)
lines(gmdh_pred ,col=4,lwd=1)

legend(x = "bottomleft",        
       legend = c("original", "GMDH", "RandomForest"),  
       col = c(8,4,2), lwd = c(5,1,1))
```

Comment: Why even study a case where the test set is not similar to the training set?

Comment: well HMDH as you can see it works good, I wonder why

Comment: Might the reason be that GMDH naturally accommodates a model like y=s1+s2+s3, while trees (in a forest) do not? If you tried a linear model, you would get about the same performance as from the GMDH, would you not?

Comment: I am not an expert in machine learning so my questions may be stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in [Random forest regression not predicting higher than training data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/235189/60613), Random Forests are based *on averages of subsets of values of the response variable in the training set*, and thus, naïvely, cannot predict values lower or higher than what the training examples themselves demonstrate.

The GMDH (a regression over basis functions) can have terms that match the data generating process, thus allowing it to extrapolate. In fact, you gave it the exact same terms that generated the data.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I noted in a comment to the OP. *on averages* could be expanded into *on averages of subsets of values of the response variable in the training set*, that would make it even clearer (at least to me).

Comment: I incorporated it, thanks @RichardHardy :)